# compass config file location / name

Tags: ruby, grails, config, compass-sass

I'm new to `Compass` (and `Ruby` too), and I'm wondering about the naming convention of the `Compass` config file.

As a default, `Compass` creates a file called `config.rb` within the directory where the `compass create` command is executed. As I'm developing a `Grails` web app, I try to initialize it within `C:\Source\MyGrailsProject\web-app\config` as I want to have all configuration files within one directory so that I could remove it from the created `WAR` file easily.

Now, I read that the name of the configuration file can also be like `config/compass.rb` [1] and I tried the following:

- create the `Compass` configuration file with all specific settings under the `config` directory
- run `compass create C:\Source\MyGrailsProject\web-app --bare` from the command line (`--bare` is used to not have `Compass` creating the default directory structure as this is a already set up project [2])
- delete the created `config.rb` file from the `web-app` folder, as I previously created the configuration file under `config/compass.rb`
- run `compass compile C:\Source\MyGrailsProject\web-app` or, alternatively `compass compile C:\Source\MyGrailsProject\web-app\config` - both of them show the "Nothing to compile ..." log which also comes up if `Compass` is not set up at all!

**what am I doing wrong here? shouldn't it be possible to so?**

---

[1] https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/751

[2] https://groups.google.com/d/msg/compass-users/w1wZd4bKbGo/vNlYJTgCm4kJ

Comment: where you have put your source files? what path do you configure in `compass.rb`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov all dir directives are within the `web-app` folder, at the same hierarchy as the `web-app/config` folder - e.g. the css directory is located at `web-app/css`. therefore I configured all `dir` directieves like so: `css_dir = "../css"`, `sass_dir = "../sass"`, etc.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov AHHHHH - and that was, what I did wrong!!! I declared the directories relative to the `compass.rb` file and not relative to the directory where I initialized `Compass`!! so, I changed the dir directives from `css_dir = "../css"` to `css_dir = "css"` and all is up and running! thanks a lot for taking me into the right direction ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @IgorArtamonov stated in his first comment on my initial question, I had declared the wrong directory paths within my `config` file. this issue was not obvious for me as I thought, that I had to declare the directory paths relative to the config file - instead, one has to declare the directory paths relative to the compass project path...

so, let's say I have my `Compass Project Path` at `/path/to/my/project` and my config file is located under `/path/to/my/project/config/compass.rb`. all other files are also in miscellaneous subdirectories like this:

`/path/to/my/project`

`/path/to/my/project/config/compass.rb`

`/path/to/my/project/css/style.css`

`/path/to/my/project/js/app.js`

`/path/to/my/project/scss/style.scss`

the directories declared in `compass.rb` have to be relative to the `Compass Project Path`, like this:

```
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss
...
```

just in case someone else will also come accross this issue ;)